# A way to reverse all prototype re-definitions?

Tags: javascript, security, overriding, prototype

Let's assume that I do not trust the browsers visiting my website. What if they for example override `XMLHttpRequest.prototype` and redirect or change the requests. Is there any way to prevent this? Perhaps by resetting all objects to "factory settings" at the end of loading?

Comment: You can check if function is native ```(XMLHttpRequest + '').match(/\[native code\]/)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script run at first, you can save references to whatever you need like below & [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Object/freeze) it.

```js
(() => {
  const XHR = XMLHttpRequest;
  Object.freeze(XHR);

  // use XHR here ...
)();
```

Otherwise, I think it is not possible to be sure other than check if function is native - casting to string `(function + '')` should show it is native function.

And running few simple unit tests against this function to be sure it is ok.

Running units test may be necessary to be sure if functions are not changed with each other (still remains native).

```js
const alertRef = alert;
alert = console.log;
console.log = alertRef;
```

Another possible option that may be helpfull is checking functions `length` property which defines how many arguments it accepts.
Be careful with that becouse it may differ in different browsers.